# How can i make the spaceship to land automatic on the base?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The base is a red cube.
The spaceship is moving already when the game start.
When I click/press the L button the spaceship rotates to face the base and starts moving to it but then when it's getting close to the base it's behaving unexpectedly and the spaceship starts rolling around the base nonstop.

What I want is to make the landing automatic like this youtube video of blender.
I don't want the graphics but the way it's landing.

[Blender landing spaceship](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U26wQ3SlMX0)

And this is a short video clip showing my spaceship when it's start landing:

[Landing test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vV669M1R_s4&feature=youtu.be)

This is the script i'm using for controlling the spaceship and the landing part should be automatic.
The script is attached to the spaceship.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ControlShip : MonoBehaviour {

    public int rotationSpeed = 75;
    public int movementspeed = 10;
    public int thrust = 10;
    public float RotationSpeed = 5;

    private bool isPKeyDown = false;
    private float acceleration = .0f;
    private Vector3 previousPosition = Vector3.zero;
    private Rigidbody _rigidbody;
    private bool landing = false;
    private Vector3 originPosition;
    private Vector3 lastPosition;
    private const float minDistance = 0.2f;
    private Transform baseTarget;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        baseTarget = GameObject.Find("Base").transform;
        originPosition = transform.position;
        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        Debug.Log("Acc Speed: " + thrust);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (landing == false)
        {
            var v3 = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Vertical"), Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0.0f);
            transform.Rotate(v3 * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * movementspeed;

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Z))
                transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R))
                transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.P))
            {
                isPKeyDown = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.P);
                float distance = Vector3.Distance(previousPosition, transform.position);
                acceleration = distance / Mathf.Pow(Time.deltaTime, 2);

                previousPosition = transform.position;
                _rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(0f, 0f, thrust, ForceMode.Acceleration);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * movementspeed;
            var targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(baseTarget.position - transform.position);
            var str = Mathf.Min(.5f * Time.deltaTime, 1);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, str);
        }

        if (landed == true)
            TakeOff();

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.L))
        {
            landing = true;
            lastPosition = transform.position;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (landing == true && other.gameObject.name == "Base")
        {
            StartCoroutine(Landed());
        }
    }

    bool landed = false;
    IEnumerator Landed()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        Debug.Log("Landed");
        landed = true;
    }

    private void TakeOff()
    {
        if (transform.position != originPosition)
        {
            _rigidbody.AddForce(transform.up * 10);
        }

        if ((transform.position - originPosition).sqrMagnitude <= (1f * 1f))
        {
            landed = false;
            _rigidbody.useGravity = false;
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (isPKeyDown)
        {
            GUI.Label(new Rect(100, 100, 200, 200), "Acc Speed: " + acceleration);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the part of the landing, should be the part of the landing:

```
transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * movementspeed;
var targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(baseTarget.position - transform.position);
var str = Mathf.Min(.5f * Time.deltaTime, 1);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, str);
```

The spaceship have two components: Rigidbody, Use Gravity set to true. And a Box Collider.

The Base have a box collider component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have a box collider on your vehicle and it looks as though it is colliding with the terrain when your code tries to bring it in for a landing. Try switching the collider to be a trigger(tick option on collider component).

Then try it again, as this will not cause physical collisions. If it works or fails for a totally different reason you know this is the cause or a contributing factor.

EDIT: It is worth also noting that when trying to achieve this kind of effect it can be much easier to trigger an animation than try to achieve it in physics based code. Unity offers some great animation controllers and you can call an animation when you need to land since you are taking control away from the player anyway.

While doing this you could turn off the collider so you don't get any strange collision then turn it on when the ship needs to take off, provided you need that of course.

Hope it helps.